# Connecting dbeaver to postgres hosted on remote server

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, dbeaver

We are using postgres db hosted two servers away, (pardon my jargon) we usually connect through terminal like:

local =>(using google auth) ssh server 1 =>(using google auth) ssh server 2 => psql -h Hostname -U Uname -d DBName

But, this is a hectic process and I'd like to connect to the DB through Dbeaver.

I browsed online and I figured it could be done with SSH tunneling but I could only hop through one server and it does not connect to the other.

Appreciate your help, thanks in advance!

My trials:

```
ssh -A -t host1.host.server1.com \ -L 5432:localhost:5432 \ ssh -A -t queries.host.server2.com \ -L 5432:localhost:5432
```

and I couldn't successfully connect. Even if I did connect, T'd only be connected to the machine but to access the DB I'll have to run the psql command. I'm totally lost after this point.

Comment: [duplicate post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45195422/mysql-connection-in-gui-via-two-ssh-connections-on-mint) has the solution for multiple remote host connection in DBeaver

Answer (score 16):

This worked for me, but only connecting to a single remote host. Edit your connection, and in the Connection Settings->Main tab, put the following:

```
Host: localhost (or 127.0.0.1 if localhost doesn't work)
Database: your_database_name
User: your_database_user_name
Password: your_database_password
```

Then on the Connection Settings->SSH tab, enter the following:

```
Check "Use SSH Tunnel"
Host/IP: your_remote_host_name or your_remote_ip
Port: 22
User Name: your_remote_user (not database user)
Authentication Method: Public Key
Private Key: path_to_your_private_key (.pem or .ppk file)
Passphrase: your_private_key_passphrase (leave blank if you didn't use one)
```

Then test connection.

Comment: I get this error: "FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user "user_name". Do I need to edit postgresql.conf?

Comment: I would make sure that you can connect with psql on the remote box first. You may have to edit your pg_hba.config file based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50085286/postgresql-fatal-ident-authentication-failed-for-user).

Comment: The error was here : I had to replace localhost to 127.0.0.1. Not sure why, it might be the entry in config file. I am new to Ubuntu and couldn't find the config file

Comment: I edited the answer to include 127.0.0.1 as an alternative. Thanks for the info.

Comment: I am trying to connect to another server and it doesn't ask for password when I connect from Terminal. DBeaver insists on giving a password. Is there a way to handle this situation?

Comment: @rjose I got it working by adding a new linux user ``sudo adduser benjamin``, setting a password for user ``benjamin``, and then entering said password into the password field in the ``ssh`` tab of dbeaver. If you set a password for your account, it will henceforth ask on the command line.