# PostgreSQL - FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user

Tags: postgresql, centos, centos7, sqoop

I've created a simple table in postgres called `employees` in database `mytestdb`

I would like to import this table into hdfs.

```
bin/sqoop import --connect 'jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1/mytestdb' --username user -P --table employees --target-dir /user/postgres
```

But, I keep receiving an error:

> WARNING: SQLException occurred while connecting to 127.0.0.1:5432
>   org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: Ident authentication failed
>   for user "user"   at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:473)

`/var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf` set up as follows:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 ident
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            ident
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 ident
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I found a workable solution from a combination of several different sources on the web.

Edit the configuration file

```
nano /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.configuration
```

Replace the first two `ident`'s with md5, like so:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            ident
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 ident
```

Save file.

Then, restart the server

```
sudo systemctl restart postgresql
```

Lastly, `grant all privileges on database testdb to hduser;`

Comment: Ah, thanks. An update for newer users: you might need `sudo service postgresql-XX.service restart` (where XX is your Postgres release, 11 in my case) instead than `sudo systemctl restart postgresql`

Comment: In some versions, the file is located at

nano /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf

Comment: I'd been trying editing the .conf file multiple times but was using `sudo systemctl restart` post that. But, using the `service restart` command worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Check the log file in (for CentOS, probably in `/var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_log`) for more details.

If the user doesn't exist, create it.  With `psql`, you can [create a user](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-createrole.html) like:

```
create role hduser with login, superuser;
```

Or from the [command line](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/app-createuser.html):

```
createuser -s -e hduser
```

If `identd` is not installed, install it:

```
yum install authd xinetd
```

Then edit `/etc/xinet.d/auth` and change `disable = yes` to `disable = no`:

```
service auth 
{ 
        disable = no 
        socket_type = stream 
        ....
}
```

And restart the `xinetd` service:

```
systemctl restart xinetd
```

Comment: Is your server running [`identd`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-methods.html#AUTH-IDENT) on tcp port 113? What do the postgres logs say (on centos, probably /var/lib/pgsql/data/logs) ?

Comment: How would I know identd is running? I don't have /var/lib/pgsql/data/logs, but there's /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_log and then today's log: postgresql-Sun.log in this directory

Comment: That's the right log, anything useful in it?  Check if identd is running with commands like `service identd status`, `ps afx | grep identd`, `telnet localhost 113`, `netstat -a`

Comment: How would I know identd is running? `telnet localhost 113` #ftfy