# Dbeaver AWS complex connection - Login to a Ec2 via ssh from command line and then Connect to Postgres

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I am trying to connect to Postgres instance in AWS which has corporate restrictions.

1. I first SSH to an AWS Ec2 instance - 2 3 custom actions on command line.
2. Then I connect  to the PostgreSQL instance by PSQL, and use the command line to execute SQL

Is there any way we can achieve the same using dbeaver or any other client?

Comment: Checkout for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42403071/connecting-dbeaver-to-postgres-hosted-on-remote-server

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want an SSH tunnel.  DBeaver has an "SSH" tab under Connection Settings for setting this up.

Alternatively, you can use `ssh` with -L to set up a tunnel manually, and then point DBeaver to the designated local port on the `localhost` host.

Comment: thihs method above do you have any other instructions. I need to provide multiple custom answers to the SSH tunnel .. designed by corporate..